# How do I make ngFor for dictionary in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dictionary, ngfor

There is a brandsByLetter class:

```
brandsByLetter: { [id: string] : AutoServiceBrand[]; } = {};
```

And I have this construction in angularJS that I need to make in Angular11:

```
<li *ngFor="let (letter, brands) of brandsByLetter">
    {{letter}}
    {{brands}}
</li>
```

How do I make "(letter, brands) of" in Angular?

Comment: @NadhirFalta It works but when I use type X instead of any tslint writes "Argument type X is not assignable to parameter type ReadonlyMap<unknown, unknown> ". How it can be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a pipe for that:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of brandsByLetter | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

add this pipe in your code:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'keys',  pure: false })
    export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
            return Object.keys(value)//.map(key => value[key]);
        }
    }
```

Here is a working example in Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahsvig?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts